# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (32,) and (30,)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression

I'm working on a stock predict model, and I'm getting this error although they have the same values!

This is the code where I'm training the model and using the Linear Regression

```
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.2)
    clf =  LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    scorepredict = clf.score(x_test,y_test)
    predictedprice = clf.predict(x_prediction)
```

Here is where I get the error.

```
    dates = pd.date_range(start = "2018-03-28", end  = "2018-04-28")
    plt.plot(dates,color ="y")
    df["Adj. Close"].plot(color = "g")
    plt.xlim(xmin=datetime.date(2017,1,1))
```

And here is where I setup the x and y arrays.

```
predictiondays = 30
df["Prediction"] = df[["Adj. Close"]].shift(-predictiondays)
x = np.array(df.drop(["Prediction"],1))
x = preprocessing.scale(x)
x_prediction = x[-predictiondays:]
x = x[:-predictiondays]

y = np.array(df["Prediction"])
y = y[:-predictiondays]
```

EDIT:

Now, in the clf.fit get this error:

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-1.23874374  1.49125839  0.80930081 ...  0.32190385  1.01987874
1.06322504].

I didn't touch anything lul.

Comment: Shouldn't x be a two-dimensional representation? 
x = np.array( [ df.drop(["Prediction"],1) ] )

Comment: @Amirhosein It is two dimensional, no? I changed it to x = np.array( [ df.drop(["Prediction"],1) ] ), and now it says its a 3 dimensional array.